# GCD mips program that starts an infinite loop

Tags: mips, greatest-common-divisor

I'm having an issue with with my stack I believe.  I ran it a couple times step by step and each time it got to this section it would work fine until the branch which finding the number not equal to zero continue to "repeat" but it would just jump back to "GCD" without any change in the stack or arguments and thus starting the infinite loop.
I tried putting a "#" in front of the first "jal GCD" under repeat but the program would stop after reaching "lw $a2, 8($s1)" and give me an exception.  What can I do so that the quotient replaces argument 2 and can continue to search for the GCD?

```
GCD: 
addi $sp, $sp, -16  #   
sw $ra, 0($sp)      #set stack
sw $s0, 4($sp)      #
sw $a1, 8($sp)      #
sw $a2, 12($sp)     #

div $a1, $a2        #n1/n2
mfhi $s1
bnez $s1, repeat    #repeat until equals 0

addi $v0, $a2, 0
addi $sp, $sp, 16

jr $ra          #return gcd

repeat:
jal GCD
lw $a1, 4($sp)
lw $a2, 8($s1)
jal GCD
lw $a1, 4($sp)
lw $a2, 8($sp)
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall about GCD, for each step if zero doesn't occur, the program should move $a2 to $a1, and then the remainder from the divide to $a2, then loop back to the div instruction, not back to GCD.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. I'm lost in the stack part and trying to use that.  My understanding of the stack is limited and I don't think my repeat part is right.    Are you saying that instead of looping through the entire GCD I should have it skip the stack part or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you need a label just before the div instruction and you need to loop back to that instruction. The code after repeat should not be using any stack based values, it should only use the values in registers.

Comment: ok I've fixed the loop but I'm still having difficulties using the stack and understanding how to implement it.  How can I determine what to change and is there a page about using stack and learning more about it?

Comment: For this particular function, you don't need to use the stack, since the function doesn't call any other functions (no need to save $ra), and you don't need to save $a0 - $a3 or $v0 - $v1. You should return the result in $v0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mips code to find the GCD of two numbers.

```
.data
num1:.asciiz"Enter the first value:"
num2: .asciiz"Enter the second value:"

.text
.globl main
main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,num1
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 5      #User Input for num1
    syscall
    move $t0,$v0 #Storing user input in another register since $a0 will be occupied in the next command
  
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,num2
    syscall

    li  $v0, 5      #User input for num2
    syscall
    move $a1,$v0
    move $a0,$t0    #Transfering the user input for num1 in $a0

    jal GCD #Calling GCD func

    add $a0,$v0,$zero 
    li $v0,1
    syscall # print result
    li $v0, 10 # exit the program
    syscall
    
GCD:
    #GCD(num1, num2)
    # num1 = $a0
    # num2 = $a1

    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 0($sp) # Func stored in stack
    sw $s0, 4($sp) # Value stored in stack
    sw $s1, 8($sp) # Value stored in stack

    add $s0, $a0, $zero # s0 = a0 ( value num1 ) 
    add $s1, $a1, $zero # s1 = a1 ( value num2 ) 

    addi $t1, $zero, 0 # $t1 = 0
    beq $s1, $t1, return # if s1 == 0 return

    add $a0, $zero, $s1 # make a0 = $s1
    div $s0, $s1 # num1/num2
    mfhi $a1 # reminder of num1/num2 = to num1%num2

    jal GCD
    
exitGCD:
    lw $ra, 0 ($sp)  # read registers from stack
    lw $s0, 4 ($sp)
    lw $s1, 8 ($sp)
    addi $sp,$sp , 12 # bring back stack pointer
    jr $ra
return:
    add $v0, $zero, $s0 # return $v0 = $s0 ( num1)
    j exitGCD
```